# How to access variables within a subview of UITableViewCell contentView in iOS Swift Project

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am working on a Swift iOS app with a `UITableView`.  I have used `XCode Storyboard` to add some labels to a prototype cell. I have also added a custom `UIView` class to the prototype cell. I can use `viewWithTag` to access the content of the labels, but I cannot access variables within my custom `UIView`. I need to pass in some integers so that the pie chart can be properly generated.

The class of my custom view is:

```
class protoBubbleView: UIView {
var necessaryInteger = 0
```

I have assigned it a tag of 9.  I try to access it in this way:

```
let lbl : protoBubbleView  = cell.viewWithTag(9)!
lbl.necessaryInteger  = 5
```

But I receive errors indicating that viewWithTag only returns UIView and this cannot be assigned to lbl which is protoBubbleView.

How can I access the variables within this subview?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`viewWithTag` returns a regular UIView - you need to cast the returned value to protoBubbleView using the `as?` or `as!` operator, depending on what behaviour you prefer in case of a problem (i.e. when there is no view with that tag, or it is not a protoBubbleView)
For more details, see [Downcasting](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-ID338)

Comment: Yes! In addition to confirming it was correct, I upvoted your answer because you obviously took the time to really read my question and caught the special distinction of needing to use as? or as! operator and casting. That was the crucial part.

Answer (score 1):

Add `.contentView.`, as such

```
cell.contentView.viewWithTag(9)
```

Alternatively, I suggest using IBOutlets, ctrl-drag from your Storyboard into your Cell Subclass, and use cell.protoBubbleView.

Also, as Jacek said, use as!/? to make it a ProtoBubbleView to access its sub variables