# TableView in swift 3

Tags: uitableview, swift3

I am using `UITextField` in `UITableViewCell` and assign `tags` for each textFields. But after scrolling the tableView, the tags of the textFields are changed. I am using swift 3. How do I manage to make the textFields' tags constant when scrolling? I am not using storyboard.

Comment: Can you show some codes? The codes of your TableView DataSource, specifically in your `cellForRow`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access variables within a subview of UITableViewCell contentView in iOS Swift Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34701707/how-to-access-variables-within-a-subview-of-uitableviewcell-contentview-in-ios-s)

Comment: I have handled it using protocol no need to tag values

Answer (score 0):

In **Swift 3** assign the textField tag as indexPath.row

Try this code:-

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ReuseIdentifer", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        cell.textField.tag = indexPath.row
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set the tag property to the indexPath.row, and it will work fine.
Just as follows,

In cellForRowAtIndexPath: write the following:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"ReuseIdentifer", for: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

 cell.textField.tag = indexPath.row
```